# Make Styles React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have this problem. I'm trying to work with material-ui for my web design, I have this code:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  card: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(10),
    direction:"column",
    alignItems:"center",
    justify:"center",
    borderRadius: 30,
    boxShadow: ' 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22)',
    },
  contenidoFormulario: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(8),
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  avatar: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
  },
  formulario: {
    width: '60%',
    marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
  },
  botonIngresar: {
    margin: theme.spacing(3, 0, 2),
    borderRadius: 50,
  },
}));
```

And I'm using it in three diferent components (Login.js, Newaccount.js, Forgotpassword.js), how do I re-use it to avoid repeating the same code?

Comment: copy it into a file and import it where ever you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a file like `commonStyles.js` and export your style. In other components, you just need to import this style and call it inside your component. Read more about combine styles in MUI via this [issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/11517) and the [official document](https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#makestyles-withstyles-styled). Try this:

In `commonStyles.js`:

```js
...
export const commonStyles= makeStyles((theme) => ({
  card: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(10),
    direction:"column",
    alignItems:"center",
    justify:"center",
    borderRadius: 30,
    boxShadow: ' 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22)',
    },
  contenidoFormulario: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(8),
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  avatar: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
  },
  formulario: {
    width: '60%',
    marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
  },
  botonIngresar: {
    margin: theme.spacing(3, 0, 2),
    borderRadius: 50,
  },
}));
```

In `Login.js`:

```js
import {commonStyles} from '../commonStyles'
import {makeStyles} from '@material-ui/core/styles'

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  ...
  
}))


const Login = () => {
  const classes = useStyles()
  const commons = commonStyles()
  return (
    <div className={commons.card}>
      ...
    </div>
  )
}

export default Login
```